# Unable to Map element from first record of source schema to 4th record of destination schema

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am Mapping one schema which has choice group to another schema with reference of other schema with Choice group.

Unable to Map element from first record of source schema to 4th record of destination schema.

It only mapping with first record of Destination schema, no drag link if working for other records except first.

Why?

[image]

Check image, where I need to map with element in yellow, but getting mapped with red circled element only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Ignore Namespaces for Links to "False". Both namespaces were different and did not allow drag & drop in mappings.

[Image Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWH7R.jpg)